# pyコードのCython化方法

Tags: python

kivyを使用してパッケージ化されたpythonコードがあります。
構成は以下の様になっています。

```
root
　|--- __init__.py
  |--- __main__.py
  |--- test.kv
  |-appフォルダ
     |---複数のpyファイルが存在(__init__.pyを含む)
```

test.shを用意して、パッケージを実行しています。

```
 python -B -m test
```

appフォルダ内とrootの__main__.pyの各pyファイルに対して、コードの隠蔽化を図りたいのですが、Cythonにてコンパイルする場合、その方法をご指南くださいませ。

Cythonでは実現できない場合、お勧めの方法が有ればご紹介頂けるとありがたいです。

Comment: ソースコード隠したいだけならzipfileにしてしまう方法があります(パスワード付きで) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30032686/how-to-run-a-python-script-from-a-password-protected-zip

Comment: おそらくまだ[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)の傾向が強い状態なのでしょう。例えば似て非なる問題としてこんなIssueがあります。[Simplify compilation of complete applications #2011](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2011) こちらはアプリ全体をCythonで作りたいということで、目的は違いますが質問内容とは似ています。しかしCythonはそうした目的のために作られたものでは無いというコメントが最新です。そこでソースコードの隠蔽は出来ないが難読化で代替する案とかが考えられます。kivyと組み合わせ出来るか不明ですが、こんな記事が切っ掛けになるかも。[Pythonでexe化 PyInstallerを極める](https://sapporo-president.com/archives/16547), [Pythonコードを守るにはどうしたらよいのか？](https://kyogom.com/tech/pyarmor/), [Pythonスクリプトの難読化](https://lets-hack.tech/programming/languages/python/obfuscate/)

Comment: oririさん
ご提案ありがとうございました。ソースコードを隠したい意図に、配布時のリバースエンジニアリングを抑制したい意図が御座います。
pass付のzipは非常に良さそうに思いましたが、モジュール実行時にpassを指定するので、shファイルを閲覧されるとpassが分かってしまうのが難点でした。

Comment: kunifさん　当初から不慣れな使い手をご指導頂きありがとうございました。自分で調査を進めてみましても、Cythonに拘らず且つ目的が可能な限り実現できる手法を選択する方が、賢明だと判断致しました。ご指導ありがとうございます。